# Page curl - Leaves Project - Interaction elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Has anyone updated leaves page curl project to support Views with Interaction elements  ?

As of Leaves doesnot support that.

or Is there any good alternate libraries - I have tried AFKFlipper.

Comment: I ran into this problem too.  I just added more subviews that have the interactive elements to the LeavesViewController and that works.  Just kind of a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I can not recommend external libraries, jus t wanted to make sure you now that from iOS5 you can use the UIPageViewController that gives you a native page curl view controller.

You can read it's documentation here-

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

See an example here -

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

And find a lecture about it in the latest WWDC.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the sample project, you can work on it. [link.](https://github.com/brow/leaves)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need leaves. You can select the page based application in xcode 4.2 running ios 5!!