# IOS: curl from right

Tags: ios, xcode, curl

I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];


[splash removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I have an imageView "splash" and I remove it with the IBAction, but my problem is that it remove splash from left, and I want to remove it from right, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlRight nor Left in the iOS.

For IOS5 projects you can use the new UIPageViewController that is working similar to the iBooks App.

you can see my answer here with links - [Page curl - Leaves Project - Interaction elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846873/page-curl-leaves-project-interaction-elements/8469925#8469925)

For other versions you can find here a work around to set this curl:
[I want to use animation to imageview using UIanimationtransitioncurl right or left. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780488/i-want-to-use-animation-to-imageview-using-uianimationtransitioncurl-right-or-le/4780658#4780658)

Good Luck